# Render Domain Field as HTML in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a domain. User with a field description. In my Grails GSP page I can display it as:

```
${user.description}
```

The problem is that description contains valid html content like this:

```
<ul><li>test</li><li>test2</li><li>test3</li></ul><br>
```

This content should be rendered to be visible as HTML instead of a String.

**How can I render a String containing HTML as HTML on a GSP?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To generate `raw` output use any of the following:

```
${raw(user.description)}
```

or

```
${user.description.encodeAsRaw()}
```

You can read this [blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html) that details this further. In later versions the default codec being used is HTML. You can control the default codec via `Config.groovy`.